# Use of clk to give delay

Tags: verilog

I am using this  section in my testbench to give inputs .How can i use @(posedge clk) instead of #10 in this code

```
initial
 clk=1'b0;
 always  #5 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
 rst=1'b1;
 # 10 rst=1'b0;

for (i=0;i<20;i=i+1)
 begin
 a=$random;
 Pn=a[3];
 Pe=a[2];
 Ps=a[1];
 Pw=a[0];
 #10;
 if (Pn==1) begin
            Pn=0;
            #10;
            end
 if (Pe==1) begin
            Pe=0;
            #10;
            end
 if (Ps==1) begin
            Ps=0;
            #10;
            end
 if (Pw==1) begin
            Pw=0;
            #10;
            end
  end
end


endmodule
```

This is the testbench for traffic control.I have tried by using @(posedge clk ) everywhere instead of #10 but its not working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a positive clock edge every `#10` these block would be equivalent:

```
Pn=0;
#10;
Pe=0;
#10;
Pn=1;
```

With posedge:

```
Pn=0
@(posedge clk);
Pe=0;
@(posedge clk);
Pn=1;
```

The `@(posedge clk);` just waits for the condition to be met before moving on to the next line of code. If the sequencing of the stimulus looks to be a clock cycle ahead now you may need to switch to non-blocking (`<=`) assignments in the testbench ie:

```
Pn <= 0
@(posedge clk);
Pe <= 0;
@(posedge clk);
Pn <= 1;
```

Also note that your clock generation logic generated the first posedge at time 5, and you changed data at 10. So you always changed data in between clock cycles which is not how it would be typically be driven if it came from another synchronous system.

```
initial begin 
  clk = 1'b0;
end
always begin
  #5 clk = ~clk;
end
```

I find it more reliable to control the clock from one process/block :

```
initial begin 
  clk = 1'b0;
  forever begin
    #5 clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```

You could then realign your clock to steps of 10 via:

```
initial begin 
  clk = 1'b0;
  #5;
  forever begin
    #5 clk = ~clk;
  end
end
```